# EF Core Exclude Where Multiple Columns are Null or Empty

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-2.0

I have a SQL Server table called `ControlActivityChangeLog`. The table has columns `CurrentValue` and `NewValue`, of which, both are nullable nvarchars. How do I query all ControlActivityChangeLogs but exclude results where CurrentValue and NewValue are null or empty. If CurrentValue is null or empty and NewValue is not then I need that record.

I tried adding this to the below query but it ends up returning no results:

```
!x.ControlActivityChangeLogs.Any(y => string.IsNullOrEmpty(y.CurrentValue) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(y.NewValue))
```

Here is my qry:

```
var qry = _context.ControlActivities
        .Include(x => x.ControlActivityChangeLogs)
        .Include(x => x.Company)
        .Where(x => 
            !x.IsDeleted && 
            !x.IsArchived && 
            !x.ControlActivityChangeLogs.Any(y => string.IsNullOrEmpty(y.CurrentValue) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(y.NewValue)))
        .AsQueryable();


    **OTHER COLUMN FILTERS HERE**


    var results = await qry.Select(x => new ModifiedCAModel
            {
                **List Of Columns**,
                Changes = x.ControlActivityChangeLogs
                    .Where(y => y => y.ControlActivityIssueId == null && y.ControlActivityTestId == null)
                    .OrderByDescending(y => y.ChangedDate)
                    .ToList()
            }).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Where` or `Any` condition is for *including*, so you need the *inverse* of

> **exclude** results where CurrentValue **and** NewValue **are** null or empty

which is

***include*** results where CurrentValue **or** NewValue **is not** null or empty

i.e. instead of

```
!x.ControlActivityChangeLogs.Any(y => string.IsNullOrEmpty(y.CurrentValue) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(y.NewValue)))
```

you need

```
x.ControlActivityChangeLogs.Any(y => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(y.CurrentValue) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(y.NewValue)))
```

Comment: I agree and that is what I wrote. The thing I don't understand is if I add that to the Where in the qry it will not work. It returns all results. But, if I add that to the Where inside the Select then it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
the below should be able to translate to SQL correctly

var qry = _(context.ControlActivities
    .Include(x => x.ControlActivityChangeLogs)
    .Include(x => x.Company)
    .Where(x => !x.IsDeleted 
             && !x.IsArchived 
             && x.ControlActivityChangeLogs.CurrentValue != null 
             && x.ControlActivityChangeLogs.CurrentValue != ""
             && x.ControlActivityChangeLogs.NewValue != null 
             && x.ControlActivityChangeLogs.NewValue != ""
    ).AsQueryable();
```

you should check what sql is being executed tho!!!

this can be obtained but adding logging to ef.

Comment: I translated what you wrote to tsql and it seems to be returning the correct results. Your code above will definitely error out but I understood what you were trying to do. I will fix with proper linq and let you know how it works. Thanks.

Comment: thanks, yeah was just sudo code, let me know where the error is or propose the change, i tend to avoid c# functions in linq querys which i wont to be able to translate Nativity even if the c# function has a translation method built into EF. There are a lot which are not so instead of guessing which ones are or are not i just avoid.

Comment: FYI, EF Core translates `string.IsNullOrEmpty` to SQL, so there is no need to use separate conditions for `null` and `""`.